# Representing relational data in Cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, cursor

Let's say we have two SQLite tables:

**Person** 
person_id 
 first_name 
 last_name

**Pet** 
pet_id 
 person_id 
 name 
 breed

Now I want to build an activity that shows a list (RecyclerView) of persons along with their pets (could be zero to many relationship). In each list item (person), I'll show person full name, pet name, and pet breed.  I see two options of solving this.

**Option 1:** Joining the tables (AKA CursorJoiner)

```
SELECT * FROM person LEFT JOIN pet ON person.person_id = pet.person_id
```

Now once I get back to onLoaderFinished, I have a cursor with all the data I need, but there are too many rows, as I only want one row per person.  So giving this to the adapter would not solve things for me.

**Option 2:** Additional query

```
SELECT * FROM person
```

Now once I get back to onLoaderFinished, I have a cursor with all my persons, but then I need to form another query to go retrieve their pets.  This solve just feels wrong with the timing of having to update the adapter.

It feels like the root of the problem is trying to have all of my UI map directly to a single Cursor.  Surely this has been easily solved by some mechanism to honor a true relational database schema.  Obviously the hack here would be to add a comma separated column on the person table, which would get me all the data I needed at one row per person.

Thanks!

Comment: So exactly what is your question? Is it how to create the "hack" of a column containing all the pets? Is it how to perhaps present the user with a list of the pets per user (perhaps Heading may assist)? Is it that you want to present a list of all users with their pets but to only show the username once?

Comment: How do I include the relational data in the cursor that I swap on the adapter? Say my data set is one user, Joe that has four dogs.  If I join, then my RecyclerView will create four records in the list where I just need one. But within that one, I also need to know the dog names are Lee, Roy, Jenn, and Ken.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to build the list that will basically be concatenated, rather than expect some magical transformation of a list of related items to be merged in to one related????? item.

There are various ways you could invoke a method that combines the items (pet names) when getView/bindView is invoked.

You could(a) extract the list according to the person_id from the pet table

You could(b) use objects that are built from the database e.g. per and Person object, the Person object including a list of the Pet objects or just a string of the Pet names.

So assuming (b) :-

### Pet.java

```
public class Pet {

    private long mPetId;
    private String mPetName;
    private String mPetBreed;
    private long mPetOwnerId;

    public Pet(String petname, String petbreed, long petownerid) {
        this.mPetName = petname;
        this.mPetBreed = petbreed;
        this.mPetOwnerId = petownerid;
    }

    //Getters
    public long getPetId() {
        return mPetId;
    }
    public long getPetOwnerId() {
        return mPetOwnerId;
    }
    public String getPetName() {
        return mPetName;
    }
    public String getPetBreed() {
        return mPetBreed;
    }

    // This setter as id will only be known after adding a pet.
    public void setPetId(long mPetId) {
        this.mPetId = mPetId;
    }
}
```

- This is pretty basic so no explanation should be needed.

### Person.java

```
public class Person {

    private long mPersonId;
    private String mPersonFirstName;
    private String mPersonLastname;
    private ArrayList<Pet> mOwnedPets;
    private String mPetList;

    public Person(String firstname, String lastname) {
        this.mPersonFirstName = firstname;
        this.mPersonLastname = lastname;
        mPetList = "";
        mOwnedPets = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addPet(Pet pet) {
        mOwnedPets.add(pet);
    }

    public void addPets(ArrayList<Pet> pets) {
        mOwnedPets.addAll(pets);
    }

    public ArrayList<Pet> getOwnedPets() {
        return mOwnedPets;
    }

    public long getPersonId() {
        return mPersonId;
    }

    public String getPersonFirstName() {
        return mPersonFirstName;
    }

    public String getPersonLastname() {
        return mPersonLastname;
    }

    public String getPetList() {
        return mPetList;
    }

    public void setPersonId(long mPersonId) {
        this.mPersonId = mPersonId;
    }

    public String altGetPetList() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=0; i < mOwnedPets.size(); i++) {
            if (i > 0) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
            sb.append(mOwnedPets.get(i).getPetName());
            sb.append("(");
            sb.append(mOwnedPets.get(i).getPetBreed());
            sb.append(")");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

- This is mostly very basic, however altGetPetList will output a comma separated list of the pets owned by the person (with the breed in brackets).

  - Say Fred Bloggs had a Dog called Rover, a Mouse called Jerry and a Dog called Spot then this would return a String as **Rover(Dog), Jerry(Mouse), Spot(Dog)**.

Before complaining that this has nothing to do with the database :-

### The DatabaseHelper - DBHelper.java

- i.e. a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper

:-

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "peopleandpets";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String TB_PERSON = "person";
    public static final String COL_PERSON_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_PERSON_FIRSTNAME = "first_name";
    public static final String COL_PERSON_LASTNAME = "last_name";
    public static final String TB_PET = "pet";
    public static final String COL_PET_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_PET_PERSONREF = "person_id";
    public static final String COl_PET_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COL_PET_BREED = "breed";
    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String person_crtsql =
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                        TB_PERSON + "(" +
                        COL_PERSON_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                        COL_PERSON_FIRSTNAME + " TEXT, " +
                        COL_PERSON_LASTNAME + " TEXT" +
                        ")";
        String pet_crtsql =
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                        TB_PET + "(" +
                        COL_PET_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                        COL_PET_PERSONREF + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                        COl_PET_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                        COL_PET_BREED + " TEXT" +
                        ")";
        db.execSQL(person_crtsql);
        db.execSQL(pet_crtsql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public long insertPerson(String firstname, String lastname) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_PERSON_FIRSTNAME,firstname);
        cv.put(COL_PERSON_LASTNAME,lastname);
        return mDB.insert(TB_PERSON,null,cv);
    }

    public long insertPersonByPerson(Person person) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_PERSON_FIRSTNAME,person.getPersonFirstName());
        cv.put(COL_PERSON_LASTNAME,person.getPersonLastname());
        return mDB.insert(TB_PERSON,null,cv);
    }
    public long insertPet(long personid, String petname, String petbreed) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_PET_PERSONREF,personid);
        cv.put(COl_PET_NAME,petname);
        cv.put(COL_PET_BREED,petbreed);
        return mDB.insert(TB_PET,null,cv);
    }

    public long insertPetByPet(Pet pet) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_PET_PERSONREF,pet.getPetOwnerId());
        cv.put(COl_PET_NAME,pet.getPetName());
        cv.put(COL_PET_BREED,pet.getPetBreed());
        return mDB.insert(TB_PET,null,cv);
    }

    public String getPetNamesPerPerson(long id) {
        StringBuilder rv = new StringBuilder();
        Cursor csr =  mDB.query(TB_PET,
                null,
                COL_PET_PERSONREF + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},
                null,null,
                COL_PET_BREED + "," + COl_PET_NAME);
        if (csr.getCount() < 1) {
            rv.append(" has no pets");
        }
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            if (csr.getPosition() > 0 ) {
                rv.append(", ");
            }
            rv.append(
                    csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COl_PET_NAME)) +
                            "(" +
                            csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_PET_BREED)) +
                            ")"
            );
        }
        return rv.toString();
    }
    public ArrayList<Person> getPeopleAndPets() {
        ArrayList<Person> rv = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor people = mDB.query(TB_PERSON,
                null,null,null,null,null,null
        );
        while(people.moveToNext()) {
            Person p = new Person(
                    people.getString(people.getColumnIndex(COL_PERSON_FIRSTNAME)),
                    people.getString(people.getColumnIndex(COL_PERSON_LASTNAME))
            );
            p.setPersonId(people.getLong(people.getColumnIndex(COL_PERSON_ID)));
            rv.add(p);
            Cursor pets = mDB.query(TB_PET,null,
                    COL_PET_PERSONREF + "=?",
                    new String[]{
                            String.valueOf(
                                    people.getLong(people.getColumnIndex(COL_PERSON_ID)))
                    },
                    null,null,null
            );
            while (pets.moveToNext()) {
                Pet pet = new Pet(
                        pets.getString(pets.getColumnIndex(COl_PET_NAME)),
                        pets.getString(pets.getColumnIndex(COL_PET_BREED)),
                        pets.getLong(pets.getColumnIndex(COL_PET_ID))
                );
                p.addPet(pet);
            }
            pets.close();
        }
        people.close();
        return rv;
    }
}
```

- The two tables, **person** and **pet**are defined/created here as are some basic methods to insert rows.
- Two methods **`insertPersonByPerson`** and **`insertPetByPet`** cater for insert according to objects.
- Method **`getPetNamesPerPerson`** should get a list of pets as per method **(a)**.
- Method **`getPeopleAndPets()`** will return an ArrayList of Person objects each including it's ArrayList of Pet objects, enabling use of the **`altGetPetList`** method.

### Tying it all together (testing) MainActivity.java :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper mDBHlpr;               //Get an instance of the DatabaseHelper
    ArrayList<Person> people;       //The list of people

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this);   //Instantiate the DatabaseHelper

        // Add some testing data
        if(DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDBHlpr.getWritableDatabase(), DBHelper.TB_PERSON) < 1) {
            mDBHlpr.insertPersonByPerson(new Person("Fred", "Bloggs"));
            mDBHlpr.insertPerson("Tom", "Smith");
            mDBHlpr.insertPerson("Frank", "Taylor");
        }
        if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDBHlpr.getWritableDatabase(),DBHelper.TB_PET) < 1) {
            mDBHlpr.insertPetByPet(new Pet("Rover","Dog",1));
            mDBHlpr.insertPet(2,"Tom","Cat");
            mDBHlpr.insertPet(1,"Jerry","Mouse");
            mDBHlpr.insertPet(3,"Bouncy","Tiger");
            mDBHlpr.insertPetByPet(new Pet("Flipper","Dolphin",2));
            mDBHlpr.insertPetByPet(new Pet("Spot","Dog",1));
        }
        // Get the people (and therefore the pets)
        people = mDBHlpr.getPeopleAndPets();
        // Have a look at there is
        for (Person p: people) {
            Log.d("PERSON",
                    "Firstname=" + p.getPersonFirstName() +
                            "LastName=" + p.getPersonLastname() +
                            "Pets are " + p.altGetPetList());
            // Alternative Get Pet List via DB
            Log.d("PERSONPETS", mDBHlpr.getPetNamesPerPerson(p.getPersonId()));
        }
    }
}
```

### The result using both (a) and (b):-

```
01-27 07:16:21.043 2031-2031/? D/PERSON: Firstname=FredLastName=BloggsPets are Rover(Dog), Jerry(Mouse), Spot(Dog)
01-27 07:16:21.043 2031-2031/? D/PERSONPETS: Rover(Dog), Spot(Dog), Jerry(Mouse)
01-27 07:16:21.043 2031-2031/? D/PERSON: Firstname=TomLastName=SmithPets are Tom(Cat), Flipper(Dolphin)
01-27 07:16:21.043 2031-2031/? D/PERSONPETS: Tom(Cat), Flipper(Dolphin)
01-27 07:16:21.043 2031-2031/? D/PERSON: Firstname=FrankLastName=TaylorPets are Bouncy(Tiger)
01-27 07:16:21.043 2031-2031/? D/PERSONPETS: Bouncy(Tiger)
```

- PERSON output from Person objects
- PERSONPETS output directly from DB

---

Of course combining the data (pets) sort of makes the list useless other than for display. A Pet cannot be clicked say to update/delete that pet.

Personally I'd manipulate the hierarchy within the adpeter for example here's a List with 3 levels Shop-Aisle-Product. Each extracted row includes the Shop(Person), the Aisle(?) and the Product(Pet). Each Item has the potential to display all 3. However the Shop is hidden if the products is for the same shop as the last displayed, similar for the Aisle :-

[image]

The work is done in the adapter's `getView` method (ListView as opposed to RecyclerView) using :-

```
    shopinfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    aisleinfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if (position > 0) {
        long thisshopid = csr.getLong(aisle_shopref_offset);
        long thisaisled = csr.getLong(shoplist_aisleref_offset);
        csr.moveToPrevious();
        long previousshopid = csr.getLong(aisle_shopref_offset);
        long previousaisleid = csr.getLong(shoplist_aisleref_offset);
        csr.moveToNext();
        if (previousshopid == thisshopid) {
            shopinfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if (previousaisleid == thisaisled) {
            aisleinfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

---

I've never used one but I believe an Expandable ListView RecyclerView could be an option, although I believe by default you have to click to show to lower hierarchy (Pets).